# Why are these file errors show up on the site - I have "none" selected in admin

Tags: 7

I'm getting errors like these show up on the site with setting "Error messages to display" set to "none":

```
File temporary://fileGhQKBK could not be copied, because the destination directory public://css is not configured correctly.
```

Why do they still show up on the site?

Answer (score 2):

The "Error messages to display" setting only controls whether or not PHP errors/warnings/notices/etc are shown - that particular message is a 'standard' message displayed using `drupal_set_message()`, with `error` as the second parameter.

This happens in includes/file.inc, line 891.

```
drupal_set_message(t('The specified file %file could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.', array('%file' => $original_source)), 'error');
```

Since there's nothing actually throwing an exception the PHP error handling never comes into it, and the message is displayed as normal.